# Using Scala inside sublime text 3 with ensime

Tags: sublimetext3, ensime

I am facing this weird issue on Windows7 with ensime on sublime. When doing the ensime startup I encounter the following exception :

I tried to run sublime as an administrator but it did not help

Anyone with a good idea ?

```
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:26,902 [INFO ]  New Logger initialised
Created ensime environment for  C:\Mycom\depot\kernel\05.00\qa\nbi\nbi-qa-v2-perf
warning: mnemonic t not found in menu caption Tools
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-07-29 16:58:35, next run at 2016-07-29 17:58:35 or after
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,201 [INFO ]  -----------------------------------------------------------
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,201 [INFO ]  Initialising server
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,202 [INFO ]  Cache dir = C:\Mycom\depot\kernel\05.00\qa\nbi\nbi-qa-v2-perf\.ensime_cache
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,202 [INFO ]  Java home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,202 [INFO ]  Target scala version  = 2.11.8
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,208 [INFO ]  Resolving, log available in C:\Mycom\depot\kernel\05.00\qa\nbi\nbi-qa-v2-perf\.ensime_cache\Resolution\saveClasspath.log
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,209 [INFO ]  Running sbt saveClasspath (in C:\Mycom\depot\kernel\05.00\qa\nbi\nbi-qa-v2-perf\.ensime_cache\Resolution)
[Ensime] 2016-07-29 17:08:35,211 [INFO ]  Save classpath task running
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function exec_save_classpath.<locals>.worker at 0x00000000030BE8C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server in C:\Users\rquillevere\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Ensime.sublime-package", line 84, in worker
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in __init__
  File "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1110, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Comment: try answser by semudu below, I personnaly switched to linux for other reasons so I cannot test the fix below

Answer (score 0):

Sublime -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Ensime -> Settings - User

```
{
  "sbt_binary": "/path/to/sbt"
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly cannot try this as I switched to linux :D So cannot tell if this is workig or not